# Retrieving additional non DB information using Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data Rest to expose a news feed REST API. I want to add an image (location) to the entity which will be retrieved by a separate web service API call.

What is the best way to do this using Spring Data Rest or would I have to create another separate REST API call/domain object etc.?

Any sample code would be fantastic.

Comment: Don't forget to accept\upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [ResourceProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface)

> The Spring Data REST exporter executes any discovered ResourceProcessor's before it creates the output representation

```java
@Bean
public ResourceProcessor<Resource<MyEntity>> myEntityProcessor() {

   return new ResourceProcessor<Resource<MyEntity>>() {

     @Override
     public Resource<MyEntity> process(Resource<MyEntity> resource) {

      resource.add(new Link("http://localhost:8080/images/images.jpg", "image"));
      return resource;
     }
   };
}
```

Another example with access to the repository and [EntityLinks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/EntityLinks.html) object that helps to build links related to the entity..

```java
@Component
class MyEntityResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<MyEntity>> {

    @Autoware
    private MyEntityRepo repo;

    @Autoware
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    @Override
    public Resource<MyEntity> process(Resource<MyEntity> resource) {

        MyEntity entity = resource.getContent();

        // Some entity processing...

        Link link entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(entity).slash("...").withRel("...")

        resource.add(link);
        return resource;
    }
}
```

More examples of using ResourceProcessor you can find in [RESTBucks project](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. I am assuming as a list of objects are being returned, this will allow me to add an individual image to each object?

Comment: Cheers @Cepr0  